# Функция поиска самого длинного слова в строке. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

Задача.

1. Правильно ли записана функция findLongestWord(str), которая получает аргументом произвольную строку и возвращает самое длинное слово в этой строке?
2. Как реализовать проверку условия - в строке могут быть только пробелы и символы букв и цифр?

```js
'use strict';

const findLongestWord = function(str) {
  let arrStr = str.split(' ');
  let wordLength = 0;
  let longestWord;

  for (let i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i += 1) {
    wordLength = arrStr[1].length;

    if (arrStr[i].length > wordLength) {
      longestWord = arrStr[i];

      return longestWord;
    }

  }
};

// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(
  findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
); // вернет 'jumped'

console.log(
  findLongestWord("Google do a roll")
); // вернет 'Google'

console.log(
  findLongestWord("May the force be with you")
); // вернет 'force'
```

Comment: А вы тестировали свою функцию? Она работает не правильно. Попробуйте в первом тесте после  `jumped` поставить еще более длинное слово.

Comment: На самом деле функция ищет первое слово, которое по длине будет больше второго слова в строке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Термин "слово" употребляешь в контексте регулярных выражений? В регулярках "слово" - это непрерывная последовательность букв, цифр и знака нижнее подчеркивание _

```js
function findLongestWord (input) {
  return input
    .split(/\W+/)
    .reduce(
      function (longest, word) {
        return word.length > longest.length
          ? word
          : longest;
      }, 
      ''
    );
}

console.log(findLongestWord('aaa bbbbbbbb !ccc!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')); // bbbbbbbb
console.log(findLongestWord('aaa bb_b')); // bb_b
```

Answer (score 2):

### Решение

Используй `reduce` для поиска самого длинного слова:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  return str.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => (b.length > a.length) ? b : a);
};

console.log(findLongestWord('There is the longest word in a string!'));
```

Если под проверкой на пунктуацию вы имели в виду "удаление" этих символов   , то можно использовать `replace`:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var punctRE = /[\u2000-\u206F\u2E00-\u2E7F\\'!"#$%&()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\]^_`{|}~]/g;
  return str.replace(punctRE, '').split(' ').reduce((a, b) => (b.length > a.length) ? b : a);
};


console.log(findLongestWord('This, -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * ex32ample ;: {} of a = -_432 string dsa35!with `~)() punctuation'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function findLongestWord (string = " ") {
    const stringSplit = string.split(' ');
    let longestWord = "";

    for (const word of stringSplit) {
        if (word.length > longestWord.length) {
            longestWord = word;
        }
    }
    return longestWord; 
}

console.log(findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';

const findLongestWord = function(str) {
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/.test(str)) {
    return 'содержит посторонние символы!';
  }
  let arrStr = str.split(' ');
  let longestWord = arrStr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    if (arrStr[i].length > longestWord.length) {
      longestWord = arrStr[i];
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
};

// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(
  findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
); // вернет 'jumped'

console.log(
  findLongestWord("Google do a  gooooogle roll")
); // вернет 'Google'

console.log(
  findLongestWord("May the force be with! you")
); // вернет 'force'
```

Comment: В случае вызова  `findLongestWord()` не верный результат получается.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а какой должен быть результат?

Comment: @Grundy мне кажется, не пойманный Exception не ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, почему? Недопустимый ввод - исключение, вроде все логично

Comment: @Grundy В основном потому что в мире js так не принято, принято скорее undefined возвращать. У вас же не выходит Exception при попытке сделать `'a'.charCodeAt(2)` например.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, кем не принято?

Comment: @Grundy мне кажется, вы лукавите. Вы сами знаете ответ на данный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLongestWord(string) {
  const arrayWords = string.split(" ");

  let longestWord = arrayWords[0];

  for (const word of arrayWords) {
    if (word.length > longestWord.length) {
      longestWord = word;
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("May the force be with 
 you"));
```